# Why does my arrayList have null values?

Tags: java

here are some details::

1. ht is my global hashtable implementation which has Key as character
   and values is a list(arrayList) implementation of type objects.
2. I am traversing through entire hashtables and storing the keys in a character set.
3. Then storing the list(whic is of type strings) at each key value in a local arrayList implementation named arrayList.
4. But the problem is that local arrayList is always taking null value

here is my piece of code

```
public void transferRecord(recordID) {
    ArrayList<Records>  arrayList;
    Set<Character> keySet = ht.keySet();
    try {
        for(Character c : keySet) {
            arrayList = ht.get(c);
            System.out.println ("Arraylist after taking input from ht"
                                     + arrayList);
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Just before entering equla" 
                                + arrayList.get(i).getRecordID());
                System.out.println("recordID to be transferred:" + recordID);
                if ((arrayList.get(i).getRecordID()).equals(recordID)) {
                    .......
        try ends later after some operations
```

Comment: where are you adding element to arraylist?

Comment: Do you mean to overwrite your arraylist every time, or add a new element to it?  Because you are overwriting it now.

Comment: Could you create something concise and compilable that outlines the problem that you're having? There is very little that we can know by reading this.